# Prove that tanx is continuous if x belongs to R/(nπ)/2 using delta epsilon definition !

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt :- 
tanx-tany=sinx/cosx -siny/cosy = (sinx.cosy-siny.cosx)/cosx.cosy=(sin(x-y))/cosx.cosy

And we know |sin(x-y)|<=|x-y|

But the problem here is the upper bound of cosx.cosy doesn't exist ! So I am stuck here please help me out !

Any other approach of doing this would be appreciated ! 
Thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

If
$n \pi < x < y < (n+1)\pi$
then,
since $\tan(x)$
is continuous and differentiable
for
$n \pi+c< x < (n+1)\pi-c$
for any $0 < c < \pi/2$,
if
$n \pi < x < y < (n+1)\pi$
then,
by the good old
mean value theorem,
for some
$x \le z \le y$,

$\begin{array}\\
\tan(y)-\tan(x)
&=(y-x)\tan'(z)\\
&=\dfrac{y-x}{\cos^2(z)}\\
&=\dfrac{y-x}{1-\sin^2(z)}\\
\end{array}
$

And since $x$ and $y$
are bounded away from
any multiple of $\pi$,
we can show that
$1-\sin^2z$
is bounded away from zero
by a value that
depends on $c$,
which is enough to prove
continuity.